# Error while trying to filter for curly brace in kql query azure

Tags: appinsights

```
let tracesfailed = traces
| where message has 'Response : \{'
```

in the above snippet the app insights is giving error for trying to filter for the curly brace but I want to only filter for those messages which have 'Response : {' in their body

Comment: if the answer below helps, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If you still need more info, please add a comment elaborating what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the '{', just do it like this:

```
let tracesfailed = traces
| where message has 'Response : {'
```